# Buddhist social networking site?

Tags: sangha

I'm looking for more friends on the Buddhist path and would there for like to ask: **Are there any social networking sites for Buddhists**? Some features that I'm looking for:

- Friends list
- Seeing online status of friends
- Sending direct messages to a friend
- Chatting with a friend
- Open forums
- Sharing images
- News feed

Grateful for help!

Kind Regards,
Tord

Answer (score 3):

My favorite is [NewBuddhist](http://newbuddhist.com/), but I don't know that it has all those features.

I'd be interested in developing this as a project, I have been thinking of the "digital sangha" social network and I'm relieved I'm not the only one.

Comment: Thank you! I will sign up on this site and check it out more in detail. I used [Oxwall](https://www.oxwall.org/) to create an online community for a Sangha i was a member on a couple of years ago. I'm thinking of using it again for creating a more general social network for Buddhists. If you are interested in knowing more please contact me at: tord (dot) dellsen (at) protonmail (dot) com

Answer (score 3):

[Dhamma Wheel](https://dhammawheel.com/) and its sister site 
[Dharma Wheel](https://dharmawheel.net/) are forums where you can add friends, send direct messages, and chat with others.

Those two are probably the closest you will get to a Buddhist social networking site, but keep in mind that they are primarily discussion forums.

Answer (score 1):

Update, to share the merits:

### Delta-chat

Mr. Holger, chef of the developer company behind [delta-chat](https://delta.chat/en/), an email-network using, independent chat app, has joyfully given possibility of use of the software toward the Sangha of the Buddha and it's faithfull follower: [Giving the possibility to make use of a messanger-software (Delta) by Mr. Holger](https://forum.sangham.net/index.php?topic=10211.msg25061#msg25061)

May the Venerables, out of compassion for the generous giver, make use of it.

May all find a remorse-less access to the members of the Sangha and fellows with it.

Since good further developments are surely good, one may feel invited to join such undertakings: [Use of email-server based messenger - Delta similar - possible for Sangha?](https://forum.sangham.net/index.php?topic=10210.msg25047#msg25047)

In the case Venerable but also Upasaka, Upasika, would benefit and/or need an conscious given email account, may it be seen as given by the original donor to contact for request via forum.sangham.net or send an email to: samana(dot)johann[at]sangham{dot}net. An comfortable automatical registration for a given email is not developed yet.

May many be able to come together under good conditions with inspiration toward the tripple Gems and Unbond with it.

[image: screenshot chat]

Anumodana!

---

### Telegram

Dedicated for the members of Sangha of the eight directions, first the Theras and all fellows, their faithfull follower and open for all wishing to build up Upanissaya with the Buddhaparisa, the Triple Gems, by merits of many kinds, like [sangham.net](https://sangham.net/) and its [forum](https://forum.sangham.net/index.php?action=forum), my person currently looks if such as a common-world-independend possibility of a modification of telegram could be made avaliable.

Currently taken on trust, and as test, the messenger access can be found under: [t.me/joinchat](https://t.me/joinchat/AAAAAFVPhbbs5Igm7pFUiw)

[image]

If whoever having the possibilities feels inspired in work on development, currently there is an active topic: [Use and implementation of Telegram possible?](https://forum.sangham.net/index.php?topic=10010.msg23986#msg23986).

To make it most proper for good monks and serious practicing laypeople, so to be able to use on what is given and without strings, bounds trades, it sure requires some wise and good effort into the right direction, given and rightly independency.

> *The Liberal on [archery skills](https://sangham.net/en/tipitaka/sut/sn/sn03/sn03.024.than)*: 
> `Let donors build`
> `pleasant hermitages`
> `and there invite the learned to stay.`
> `Let them make reservoirs`
>    `in dry forests (internet)`
> `and walking paths`
>    `where it's rough`
> `Let them, with a clear, calm awareness,`
> `give food, drink, snacks,`
> `clothing, & lodgings`
> `to those who've become`
>    `straightforward.`

*[Note that this isn't given for stacks, exchange, world-binding trades and also not a rebel-undertaking, but simply a gift toward release from this wheel]*